# MVC Edit Post Returns Mulitple "selected" IDs for a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model, controller

So, I ran into a problem when selecting a new ID value for a foreign key field in my model. I use the `ViewBag` (yes, I know it is a dirty method) to send `SelectList` to the page. It looks like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    var carriers = db.GetMobileCarriers().Select(m => new { Id = m.Id, Name = m.Name }).ToDictionary(s => s.Id, s => s.Name);
    var notify = db.NotificationMethods.Select(n => new { Id = n.Id, Name = n.Name }).ToDictionary(n => n.Id, n => n.Name);
    ViewBag.Carriers = new SelectList(carriers, "Key", "Value");
    ViewBag.NotifyMethods = new SelectList(notify, "Key", "Value");
    Contact contact = db.Contacts.Find(id);
    if (contact == null)
    {
         return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(contact);
}
```

In the page, I am using the following to generate the HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div class="editor-label" style="vertical-align:top;">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneCarrierId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" style="width: 500px !important;">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PhoneCarrierId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Carriers)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneCarrierId)
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div class="editor-label" style="vertical-align:top;">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NotificationMethodId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" style="width: 500px !important;">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NotificationMethodId, (SelectList)ViewBag.NotifyMethods)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NotificationMethodId)
    </div>
</div>
```

My POST method in the controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact, FormCollection form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(contact).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(contact);
}
```

I only added the `FormCollection` for debugging purposes. The problem is that the returned selected `NotificationMethodId` is the same as it was before selecting a new one. It displays the properly selected Id on the GET. The weird thing is that when I look at the `FormCollection`, the data for the `NotificationMethodId` has two values for the key. One for the original and one for the newly selected Id. But the model is always binding to the first one which is the original, unedited one. The other weird thing is that it does not behave this way for the `PhoneCarrierId` field which is setup and used the exact same way. Therefore, I must be missing something.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a hidden input for the `NotificationMethodId` somewhere in your view? And the is no need for the unnecessary extra overhead of using `ToDictionary()` - it can just be `ViewBag.Carriers = new SelectList(carriers, "Id", "Name");`

Comment: By Jove I think you are right. There was still a legacy hidden for the `NotificationMethodId`. And yes, I need to go back and remove the unnecessary Select. That was part of some testing I was doing because it was originally using just a string and not binding to the Id and I was playing with the display text. Good catch on both accounts. If you want to add that as an answer, I will give you credit for it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `FormCollection` contains 2 values for `NotificationMethodId` suggests you have a second input in the view for `NotificationMethodId`, most likely a hidden input, and that it is located before the `DropDownListFor()` method (the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first value and ignore the 2nd one with the same name)

Side note: It is not necessary to use `ToDictionary()`. Instead you code t generate the select list can simply be

```
var carriers = db.GetMobileCarriers();
ViewBag.Carriers = new SelectList(carriers, "Id", "Name");
```